# .net core azure deployment failing: Project file does not exist

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an app-service app set up in Azure which is set to deploy upon commit into a team-services git repository. This has been working fine until now, and the deployment is failing with:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
```

However, If I open the azure console and CD to my project directory I can see that the project file (an asp.net core .xproj) does indeed exist. I know its in the correct directory from the output in the deployment log, showing that the packages are being restored:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest\project.json...
Committing restore...
Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest\project.json
Restore completed in 10549ms.
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'BundlerMinifier.Core' in D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient\project.json...
Committing restore...
Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient\project.json
Restore completed in 7119ms.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1IDPTest\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.0.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\IDPTest\src\IDPTest.MVCClient" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d40eb8007743fd" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\59.51109.2534\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd
```

"

Interestingly I have two app-service apps pointing at different projects in the same solution. Suddently they're both failing with the same error message even though they're deploying different projects...

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I already had a global.json in my solution root (at the same level as my .sln file) but that was pointing at an older version of the SDK, so I updated this and it made no difference. I then tried getting rid of the 'test' project in the json file and that made no difference either. Still failing with the same error[image]

Comment: Did you file a ticket somewhere public? I just experienced this as well.

Comment: @ThomasArdal No, not sure where they need to be filed. Good in a way it isn't just me. Tried re-deploying a couple of minutes ago. Same issue

Comment: Maybe here: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Support

Comment: Adding the global.json file worked for me.

Comment: @ThomasArdal - so you didn't have one before? I already had one and updating it to the latest version of the SDK hasn't made any difference to me :(

Comment: @LDJ you need to remove the one in the solution and put it at the root of the repository and let the version of the SDK compatible with the one used in your project. Azure has updated its version to preview3, I think you are using preview2-something like the rest of us.

Comment: @LDJ Nope, didn't have one. I do now :)

Comment: I hade the same issue, and adding global.json to the root helped me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently you need to specify the SDK version explicitly in your global.json otherwise Kudu is using the latest which is now the preview3 one which is not compatible.

```
{
"projects": [ "src", "test" ],
"sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
    }
}
```

Be careful, you global.json file should live at the root of your repository.

Details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a301f82-6a7a-4c03-ad4a-bd8714d72ba6/continious-deployment-of-aspnet-core-app-suddenly-starts-to-fail-today?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required

Comment: This hasn't helped for me. I already had a global.json file in my repository root, so I updated it to the latest SDK version but I'm still getting the same deployment errors

Comment: @LDJ if you have a repro where global.json does not work, please take a look through https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2230, and add to that as necessary.

Comment: @LDJ I had the same problem today and it seems to be a bug on Azure only, reported here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4804 Try to do dotnet build without the path but being in the correct directory before you run the command.

Comment: For all those who came here like me for a fix, if you don't know what version run `dotnet --version` from the command prompt and then replace the SDK version with the console output

Comment: Thanks! A literal copy/paste of the global.json above helped me!